# Complex Query: Select latest object from every day, or if present, a flagged object

Tags: python, sql, django

Okay, so I'm working with a blog (zinnia) and the model is Entries.  I want to craft a special query that does the following:

1. Select a max of one entry per day.
2. If an entry is marked "featured", select that one.
3. Otherwise select the latest one

Abridged model:

```
class EntryAbstractClass(models.Model):
    """Base Model design for publishing entries"""
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(_('creation date'),
                                         default=timezone.now)
    start_publication = models.DateTimeField(_('start publication'),
                                             blank=True, null=True,
                                             help_text=_('date start publish'))
    end_publication = models.DateTimeField(_('end publication'),
                                           blank=True, null=True,
                                           help_text=_('date end publish'))
    featured = models.BooleanField(_('featured'), default=False)
```

To further complicate things, the entry date used for "latest" is:

```
if start_publication != None:
    latest_date = start_publication
else:
    latest_date = creation_date
```

I'm not sure how I would do this in SQL, much less django filters.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Hrmm, maybe using the Q object?  I'm not sure I 100% understand, check this out:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

How about something like this (totally untested):

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db.models import Q

filters = Q()

# If an item is featured
filters |= Q(featured=True)

# or if it was "published" today
filters |= Q(start_publication__day=datetime.today())

# or if it was "created" today
filters |= Q(creation_date__day=datetime.today())

# grab just one
entry_of_the_day_yall = Entries.objects.filter(filters)[:1]
```

Comment: Thanks, the Q object is definitely what I will end up using, but really I need some method of *nesting* them so that I can run a query similar to what you've written for each daily subset.

Comment: I think you can just nest them... I think?! `Q(Q(something) | Q(more things))`